# Plotting Data Points and Interpolating

Tags: r, google-maps, unicode, spatial-interpolation

I want to plot the data on the map and interpolate it but i do not know how to do it in r. This is what i have done so far.

```
library(ggmap)

gc <- geocode("Rakiraki,Fiji")
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Rakiraki,Fiji&sensor=false
map <- get_map(gc)
Map from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-17.399264,178.070532&zoom=10&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&sensor=false
(bb <- attr(map, "bb"))
     ll.lat   ll.lon   ur.lat   ur.lon
1 -17.81878 177.6318 -16.9801 178.5107
(bbox <- bb2bbox(bb))
     left    bottom     right       top 
177.63177 -17.81878 178.51067 -16.98010 
ggmap(map) 
+ geom_point(
+ + aes(x = lon, y = lat),
+ + data = gc, colour = "red", size = 3
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"+ aes(x = lon, y = lat),
+ data ="
+ )
Error: unexpected ')' in "+ )"
data1 <-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
data1
  Longitude Latitude Wind.Speed
1     177.8    -17.6        4.0
2     177.5    -17.5        3.5
3     178.0    -17.4        4.5
4     178.1    -17.6        4.0
5     178.2    -17.3        6.0
6     178.3    -17.7        6.5
7     178.3    -17.5        5.0
8     178.4    -17.6        5.5
```

Can anyone tell me how can i plot these data and how to interpolate it on the map.

[image: Map Obtained in R]

I want the final map to look something like this. Please find attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOdtK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of issues with the code in your question. The parentheses are not closed at the end of `geom_point` and there are `+` symbols present which should not be there.

I am assuming you want to add the data in `data1` to the map, *i.e.* wind speed at different locations. Something like this should work:

```
ggmap(map) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Longitude,
                 y = Latitude,
                 size = Wind.Speed),
             data = data1, 
             colour = "red")
```

[image]

It's not clear exactly what you mean by "interpolate" but perhaps something like `stat_density2d` is what you had in mind? Add this to the above code:

```
+ stat_density2d(data = data1, 
                 aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to make a choropleth map. Can you show me how to go about making that. Thanks